# records inserted in a sqlite table are the same for each row

Tags: android, json, sqlite, sql-insert

I have a JSONArray which contains many records. I want to compare a string inside those object with a similar(I know it has the same value) record in my SQLite db. but when I loop the table each row value has the first row value.

INSERT A RECORD TO DB >> it returns different value

```
        ArrayList<String> fieldsNameTasse = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> fieldsValueTasse= new ArrayList<String>();



        for (int i = 0; i < pagamenti.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject row = pagamenti.getJSONObject(i); /** LOOP OGGETTI */

            String fattura = row.getString("Fattura");
            String descrizione = row.getString("Descrizione");
            String scadenza = row.getString("Data Scadenza");
            String importo = row.getString("Importo");
            String stato = row.getString("Stato Pagamento");


            // FATURA SHOW ALL DIFFRERENtS VALUE CORRECTLY
            fieldsNameTasse.add("fattura");
            fieldsValueTasse.add(fattura);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), fattura.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            fieldsNameTasse.add("descrizione");
            fieldsValueTasse.add(descrizione);

            fieldsNameTasse.add("scadenza");
            fieldsValueTasse.add(scadenza);

            fieldsNameTasse.add("importo");
            fieldsValueTasse.add(importo);

            fieldsNameTasse.add("stato");
            fieldsValueTasse.add(stato);

            DBmanager.insert("TasseIncoming", fieldsNameTasse, fieldsValueTasse);


        }
```

CHECK DB ROW VALUE << it returns always the first value

```
        /** SHOW ALWAYS THE SAME VALUE*/
        int counter = 0;
        Cursor cursor = DBmanager.readAll("TasseIncoming");
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String ffattura = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fattura"));
            counter++;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ffattura+" - "+counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Have you thought about erasing the current contents of those `ArrayList`s each time through the loop, or just moving their definitions inside the loop?

Comment: ok. this is the solution! Thx to much. If you post it i wil mark as right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
 ArrayList<String> fieldsNameTasse = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> fieldsValueTasse= new ArrayList<String>();
 for (int i = 0; i < pagamenti.length(); i++) {
   // add stuff to the above arraylists
   DBmanager.insert("TasseIncoming", fieldsNameTasse, fieldsValueTasse);
}
```

Every time you loop, you're just adding values to the end of what's already in those `ArrayList`s. So there's lots of duplicate column names with different values for each. Some quick testing:

```sql
sqlite> create table foo(a, b);
sqlite> insert into foo(a,b,a,b) values(1,2,3,4);
sqlite> select * from foo;
a           b         
----------  ----------
1           2
```

indicates that when a column is included multiple times in an `INSERT`, only the first corresponding value is used. Hence only ever getting the values from the first iteration of the loop.

The easy fix is to move those variable definitions *inside* the loop, so each insert is done with a fresh set of columns and values:

```java
 for (int i = 0; i < pagamenti.length(); i++) {
   ArrayList<String> fieldsNameTasse = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> fieldsValueTasse= new ArrayList<String>();
   // add stuff to the above arraylists
   DBmanager.insert("TasseIncoming", fieldsNameTasse, fieldsValueTasse);
}
```